# c# Openfiledialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

When I open a file using this code

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName, Encoding.Default);
```

A window appear and ask me to choose file (The File Name is blank as you can see on the image)

[image]

If I press second time the button Open to open a file the File Name show the path of the previous selected file (see on image) How I can clear this path every time he press Open button?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably using the same instance of an `OpenFileDialog` each time you click the button, which means the previous file name is still stored in the `FileName` property. You should clear the `FileName` property before you display the dialog again:

```
ofd.FileName = String.Empty;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
ofd.FileName = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the filename.

```
   openFileDialog1.FileName= "";
```

Or

```
   openFileDialog1.FileName= String.Empty()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply add this line before calling `ShowDialog()`:

```
ofd.FileName = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear just the filename (and not the selected path), you can set the property `FileName` to `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = sender.ToString();
    }
```

What about this one.